# How do I get a string from a char?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm having trouble when trying to get a `char` from a `string`.

the code is:

```
let op = read_line () in
print_endline (op.[1]);
```

but when I try to compile it, the following message appears:

> Error: This expression has type char but an expression was expected of
>   type
>            string

I also tried to put the result in a variable and print it later,

```
let op = read_line () in
let ch = op.[1] in
print_endline ch;
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: And for when you want to go the other way, `String.make 1 'a'`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found out why!

`print_endline` expects a `string`, but the `String.[n]` returns a `char`.

I just changed `print_endline` to `print_char` and it worked.

Comment: you can use tools like `merlin` to help you know the types before having to get compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `print_char` you could use `String.sub` which will return a string, even if we specify we only want one character.

```
# let op = read_line () in
  print_endline @@ String.sub op 1 1;;
hello
e
- : unit = ()
```